# iptables: trying to block port 53 but not working

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm messing around with IP tables and I'm trying to do the following:

I have several hosts on the same network: 192.168.1.0/24. The DNS server is 192.168.1.1.

I'm trying to prevent all the hosts from making any DNS requests, either to 192.168.1.1 or to the internet (i.e. 8.8.8.8 Google DNS). I tried the following:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

But none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to post your entire iptables ruleset, not just random things you tried. Please edit your question and include the output of `iptables-save`.

Comment: There is nothing in iptables. I ran iptables -F before issuing the commands.

Comment: Are the other hosts on the network routing through this host? If you do a `tcpdump`, can you see the DNS traffic being passed?

Comment: Yes, if i run tcpdump on this host, they pass through it.

Comment: Are you sure they go through it?  They'd all be in the same collision domain as the DNS server so would not need a router at all.  You would be able to see arps between them even if the packets aren't passing through the firewall system

Comment: We also need a network diagram.   Does 192.168.1.1 act both as firewall and router, or do you have 2 seperate boxes?   Also, we may need to see the IPTABLES rules - I suspect there is a problem with ordering - please provide the output of iptables -vnL

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add one rule (as shown below) to the OUTPUT table.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

Here is a example where I tried to resolve my domain with and without the rule to illustrate it.

```
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short selvans.net @8.8.8.8
76.185.134.208
arul@cheetah:~$ sudo iptables -F
arul@cheetah:~$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short selvans.net @8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
arul@cheetah:~$ sudo iptables -F
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short selvans.net @8.8.8.8
76.185.134.208
```

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong - the OUTPUT table does not work with packets which are traversing through it - only traffic originating from the address - This would have worked if you are testing from a local machine, but not a router - which requires both output (for the router to be blocked) and forwarding (for everything else) chains to be modified

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is wrong. This is actually the easiest way to accomplish the intent of the OP without going through networking changes as explained by @mfarver

Comment: This assumes that all the hosts are Linux boxes - and that the OP controls all the hosts.  If he did, why would he need to ask this.  Also, using "-A" rather then "-I" would mean the rule is appended, and probably not seen - for the same reason the OP's rules probably don't work - Centos - and almost certainly others have an explicit rule blocking traffic, rather then rely on the default.  Further it does not block port 53 traffic to 192.168.1.1 as requested by the OP - and the equivalent rule for that host fails as the OP has pretty much stated.

Answer (score 0):

If the DNS server and the hosts are on the same subnet (192.168.1.0/24) it is extremely unlikely that the packets traverse the machine that you are setting IPtables rules on.  Devices on the same subnet normally send packets directly without the use of a router.

You will need to either set the IPtables output rule on all devices, or you will need to restructure the network by placing either the clients or the DNS server) on separate subnets with the iptables machine in between.

Once you get the packets crossing the iptables machine this rule will work:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

or you can set this rule on every client machine:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```